# NoMethodError in Associated model's form object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I am building a project management app.
My System is like- A project has many features, A feature has many tasks.
And the routes.rb is defined as

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :features do
      resources :tasks
    end
  end
```

The first level , that is project to feature is working fine for new feature form , but when I try to implement new tasks form as ->

```
  <%= form_for([@feature, @feature.tasks.build], class: "form-group row") do |form| %>

    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, required:true, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= form.submit class: "btn btn-primary m-2" %>

  <% end %>
```

> Now its showing error as

[image]

Here is my models->

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :feature
end
class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :tasks
end
```

**And the controller for tasks looks like->**

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController  
  before_action :set_feature

  def new
    @task = @feature.tasks.new
  end

  def create
    @task = @feature.tasks.new(task_params)

    if @task.save
       redirect_to project_features_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update

    if @task.update(task_params)

      redirect_to project_feature_tasks_path
    else
      render :edit
    end

  end

  def complete
    @task.update(completed: true)
    redirect_to project_feature_tasks_path
  end

  def destroy
    @feature.task.destroy
    redirect_to project_feature_tasks_path
  end


  private

  def set_feature
    @feature = Feature.find(params[:feature_id])
  end

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:name,:completed, :project_id,:feature_id)
  end

end
```

Any help is very much appreciated - I am stuck with this error for days now.

Answer (score 1):

If you try running `$ rails routes` you can see why your current routes are failing you.

```
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
    project_feature_tasks GET    /projects/:project_id/features/:feature_id/tasks(.:format)                               tasks#index
                          POST   /projects/:project_id/features/:feature_id/tasks(.:format)                               tasks#create
 new_project_feature_task GET    /projects/:project_id/features/:feature_id/tasks/new(.:format)                           tasks#new
edit_project_feature_task GET    /projects/:project_id/features/:feature_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format)                      tasks#edit
     project_feature_task GET    /projects/:project_id/features/:feature_id/tasks/:id(.:format)                           tasks#show
                          PATCH  /projects/:project_id/features/:feature_id/tasks/:id(.:format)                           tasks#update
                          PUT    /projects/:project_id/features/:feature_id/tasks/:id(.:format)                           tasks#update
                          DELETE /projects/:project_id/features/:feature_id/tasks/:id(.:format)
```

You would have to call:

```
form_for([@project, @feature, @feature.tasks.build], ...) do |form|
```

A better idea is to unnest the routes. You can do this by using the [`shallow` option](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting):

```
resources :projects do
  resources :features, shallow: true do
    resources :tasks
  end
end
```

Or you can do it like so if you for some reason want to keep the member routes (show, edit, update, destroy) for  features nested:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :features
end

resources :features, only: [] do
  resources :tasks
end
```

Comment: On a side note its better to do `form_for([@feature, @task], ...)` and assign `@task = @feature.tasks.new` in the controller. It lets you reuse the form in your create, edit and update actions.

Comment: if i use shallow nesting then what would the form_for look like?

Comment: i tried the first way and also your comments , but everytime its showinng  `undefined method `tasks' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Exactly like in your original question. Use `rails routes` to check the output.